# ajax call to WCF service error "405 Method Not Allowed"

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf

I have a webservice & I am calling it using jquery ajax call
the service is hosted in a project that also hosts silverlight project
in web.config, i have

```
<system.webServer>    
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

endpoint config is

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="ThreeBirds.HttpServiceBehavior" name="TheWire.Server.Endpoints.LeadCaptureService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="AspNetAjaxBehavior" name="LeadCaptureService" contract="ThreeBirds.Services.Contracts.ILeadCaptureService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
```

and custom behavior config is

```
<behavior name="AspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
```

so when I call the webservice from javascript to post the data, I get '405 method not allowed' error

```
var webMethod = 'RecordSubscribe';
                                        var formFields = {

                                            dealerid: dealerID,
                                            firstname: $(form).find(".inputFirstName").val(),
                                            lastname: $(form).find(".inputLastName").val(),
                                            email: $(form).find(".inputEmail").val()
                                        };

                                        $.ajax({
                                            type: "POST",
                                            url: "http://thewire.3birdsmarketing.com/wire/endpoints/Leadcapture.svc/Record" + webMethod,
                                            processData: false,
                                            contentType: "application/json",
                                            data: JSON.stringify(formFields),
                                            allowCrossDomain: true,
                                            dataType: "json",
                                            success: function (data, status, req) {                                                
                                                alert("Thank you " + formFields.firstname + " " + formFields.lastname + ", your information has been submitted.");

                                            },
                                            error: function (data) {
                                                alert('Sorry ! There was an error sending your data. Please try it again.');
                                            }
                                        });
```

In Chrome, the service does succeed but in IE (10) & firefox (19) it fails & i get the error message. Chrome first does OPTIONS request which results in 405 just like those in IE & firefox but after that chrome does another POST request automatically & that comes up with 200. IE & Firefox don't do this another POST request.

Is there anything I am missing? 
Thanks for your answers

Comment: Are you consuming the service cross-domain?  Just checking for that possiblity.